# How to name radio button values inside a radio button group in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-material

So I have a form with many of the questions that are in a radio button group. My problem is that I want to name each of the values depending on the server's response. My code is as follows.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in qc.questions track by $index"  type={{item.type}}>
      <br> <b>Q)</b> {{item.question_text}}<br><br>

     <md-radio-group ng-model="qc.formData[answer][$index]" ng-if="item.type==='radio'||!item.type" >
        <div ng-repeat="answer in item.answers track by $index">
      <md-radio-button value="answer{{$index}}" class="md-primary">{{answer}}</md-radio-button>
        </div>
    </md-radio-group>

    <div ng-repeat="answer in item.answers track by $index" ng-if="item.type==='checkbox'||!item.type">
    <md-checkbox ng-model="qc.formData[answer]" >
            {{answer}}
    </md-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code I am able to set the values of the data with value="answer{{$index}}" and it sets values of the radio buttons as intended. But i would like to name each one of the values depending on the server response too, I am not able to do that. Right now the name starts from 0 and goes up to how many radio buttons there are. For example 0:"Ans2",1:"Ans2",3:"Ans1",3:"Ans4". I want to name and replace those numbers with something i get from the server like "Q1":"Ans2","Q2":"Ans2","Q3":"Ans1","Q4":"Ans4". How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry in advance if I misunderstood you, but I think that you just need to do like this: value="Q{{$index+1}}" that will produce for $index 0 value "Q1",and so on.

Comment: But I don't want it to increment by 1 each time. Q# could be any as the questions are shown based on the servers response and grabbed from question bank. So in one flow the questions could be Q1 Q6 Q9 .... how can I name the my key value pairs like that. My values are my answers, but with the current code my keys are index numbers which I want to be Q# as I explained.

Comment: I presume then that in qc.questions you have those questions names, like Q1, Q6,, if that is the case you do <md-radio-button value="{{item.name}}".. > If not please provide example of qc.questions and result you vant to acheve.

Comment: Yes exactly, in qc.questions i have names for each questions, but i want them assigned to the key, and not the value. The values would be my answers. But the keys i want the Q#. For example: {"Q3":"A7","Q6":"A3"}. Right now, its configured like {0:"A7","1:"A3"} Its based on the index number of the array, and i want to replace the names with my own data that i get from the server. Thanks!

Comment: Please try value="{{item.name}}:{{answer}}".

Comment: Now its like {"0":"Q10:A20"}. Its assigning index number still and treating the question number and the answer as a value. What i want to achieve is {"Q10":"A20"}. :(

Comment: Where did that index  (number ) coming from? Does your item.name have that  index in it? Can you please paste here one example of item.name and one of the answer?

Comment: There is no item.name. I put item.question_number because thats what i wanted. My server's response looks like this.
Array(10)
0
:
answers
:
(2) ["A1", "A2"]
id
:
"59bb5e6bec0cdf3fa25b1898"
question_number
:
"Q1"
question_text
:
"Employee preference "
type
:
"radio"
This is an example of one of the item in the items array.

Comment: value="{{item.question_number}}:{{answer}}". Sorry if I couldn't help more.